# What's the right way to build a asset source map in JavaScript/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, assets

I need to create a source map for a list of SVG assets in my app where each asset has a set of properties. Example:

```
const myAssetMap = {
    dog: {
        name: Dog,
        svg: Dog.svg,
        bkgColor: '#EEE',
        textColor: '#FFF',
    },
    cat: {
        name: Cat,
        svg: CatFile.svg,
        bkgColor: '#EEE',
        textColor: '#FFF',
    },
    ....
}
```

Later, I can then find the desired properties like so:

```
const getMyParams = (name, type) => {
    return myAssetMap[name][type];
};
```

Is this the right way to do this? Would love to learn if there is a better way.

Comment: Looks good to me

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is no right answer, but you approach looks reasonable :)